# How do I delete the text which is displayed by text("text",x,y) of Processing?

Tags: java, processing

I've wrote the following code which draw the numbers 1,2,3 on the screen with delay(intentionally).

```java
void func(String s,int x,int y,int size){
    fill(0);  
    textSize(size);
    text(s,x,y);
    return;
}

void setup(){
    size(600,600);  
}

int i=0;   
void draw(){
    if(i==0){f("1",100,200,30);i++;}
    delay(1000);
    if(i==1){f("2",100,300,30);}
    delay(1000);
    if(i==2){f("3",100,400,30);}
    delay(1000);
}
```

Of course this code finally display 3 numbers on the screen but what I want to do is to delete the certain number(s) by some function or operation.

How do I implement it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not delete anything what is draw in the display window but you can draw something on top of it or clear the entire window.

[`draw()`](https://processing.org/reference/draw_.html) is executed continuously and the entire scene is redrawn in every frame. You don't need any [`delay`](https://processing.org/reference/delay_.html) in `draw()`.
Clear the screen by [`background()`](https://processing.org/reference/background_.html) and use [`str()`](https://processing.org/reference/strconvert_.html) to convert the integral number `i` to a string.
The frame rate can be set by [`frameRate()`](https://processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html).

See the example:

```java
void setup(){
    size(600,600);  
    frameRate(10);
}

int i=1;   
void draw(){
    background(196);
    func(str(i),100,200,30);
    i ++;
}

void func(String s,int x,int y,int size){
    fill(0);  
    textSize(size);
    text(s,x,y);
    return;
}
```

[image]